# CalendarView gets white in Alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, calendarview

I am trying to implement a `CalendarView` in an `AlertDialog`. It works fine except for how the calendar turns completely white which leads to the numbers being barely readable and there are no lines between them. Does anybody have a clue why this is the case?

Here is my code:

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CalendarView
android:id="@+id/calendarID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="300dip"
android:tag="my tag" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and

```
public void onClickZumKalendar(final View view){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService
              (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    FrameLayout ll= (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_dialog, null, false);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMessage("something")
    .setView(ll)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //do nothing...yet
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
    ).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property you want for the text color is:

```
android:focusedMonthDateColor
```

Here is an example edit to your code which results in a green background and large black text:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarID"
        android:background="@color/light_green"
        android:dateTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:focusedMonthDateColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dip"/>
</FrameLayout>
```